# Keep a div in the center of the page on zoom

Tags: html, css

I have an image and text in a div and I'm trying to keep it in the center of the page when I zoom. I tried setting padding-top as 30vh and 30% and it keeps the top side of the black box in the same place and resizes the rest of the box. I tried setting position:absolute; top:50%; left:50% and the div shrinks to the top left corner of the box. Is there a way to make it shrink to the point in the dead center of the viewport?

Here's the page at 100% zoom and 30% zoom respectively

[image: 100% zoom]

[image: 30% zoom]

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  display: flex;/*align child vertical*/
  justify-content: center;/*align child vertical*/
  align-items: center;/*align child vertical*/
}
.child{
  background-color: purple;
  width: 75%;
  height:50%;
  display: block;/*align horizontal*/
  margin-left: auto;/*align horizontal*/
  margin-right: auto;/*align horizontal*/

}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
</div>
</div>
```

the code don't work here
so use [this stack blitz code to run](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-gdtsh1?file=styles.css)